# Fold expression as argument of [] operator

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a fold expression as the argument of the [] operator. Unfortunately, only the first element is correct.

```
template <class ...U> T& operator[](U ...indices){
    size_t i=0, k[get_n_dimensions()];
    (... , void(k[i++]=indices));
    // use k[0], k[1], ...
    // only k[0] is correct
}
```

However, if I use the same syntax for the argument of a function, it works fine.

```
template <class ...U> T get(U ...indices) const {
    size_t i=0, k[get_n_dimensions()];
    (... , void(k[i++]=indices));
    // k[0], k[1], ... filled correctly
}
```

What is the reason? What would be the solution?

Comment: `k[get_n_dimensions()]`? That's not C++.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: why not?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: `get_n_dimensions()` can be `constexpr`, else, indeed, it would be VLA.

Comment: Sorry it's a remnant of the rest of the code. To make it self-contained, I could have replaced it by sizeof...(indices).

Comment: Indeed, it could be `constexpr`.

Comment: If I use instead `size_t k[sizeof...(indices)];`, the second argument is correct but not the following ones.

Comment: Aside: you can simplify this to `size_t i = sizeof...(indices); size_t k[] = { indicies... };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ does not have multi-dimensional indexing, and that's "hard-wired" into the syntax - you can't add it by overloading.

The reason that your code compiles at all is that `p[a,b]` is equivalent to `p[(a,b)]` - that is, it uses the regular comma operator which will compute `a` and ignore the result, then produce the value of `b` as the index into `p`.

Thus, your template is never used "variadically", but is essentially the same as

```
template <class U> T& operator[](U indices)
```

You need to name the function, or overload an operator that can take more than one parameter, such as `operator()`.

Comment: You have triggered my too-much-snark detector, and I didn't think *that* was possible....

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that it would not be possible with the [] operator. But since it compiled...

Answer (score 7):

> What is the reason?

The array subscript operator (`operator[]`) must have exactly one argument. The first snippet you have shown is invalid for any `sizeof...(U) != 1`.

A function template like `get` or another operator like `operator()` do not have a similar limitation.

---

> What would be the solution?

Do not use `operator[]`.

Comment: I suppose what OP should do is use `operator()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the subscripting operator `operator[]` must accept only a single parameter.

See [over.sub] (**emphasis mine**)

> `operator[]` shall be a non-static member function **with exactly one parameter**. It implements the subscripting syntax

However, that one parameter doesn't have to be an integer.

You could still do what you want if you are able to move your values into a [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) like so:

```
template<size_t... indices>
T& operator[](std::index_sequence<indices...>){
    size_t i=0, k[get_n_dimensions()];
    (... , void(k[i++]=indices));
    // ...
}
```

You'd call it like so

```
my_instance[std::make_index_sequence<3>{}]; // passes 0, 1, 2 to the function
```

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kOvbSbQvREdVb3ZZ)